# Input range progress bar color Chrome With TypeScript React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Hello I create a slider in typescript react on chrome but I find no solution on stackoverflow or another website to my problem which is to put two different color one before the thumb and one after.

here is the function of my input range

```
export function Slider(props: SliderProps) {
  const cssProps = {
   ...getCssPropertiesForType(props.type ?? 'default'),
 }


 return (
   <input
     type="range"
     value={props.valueX ?? ''}
     step="1"
     min={props.minX}
     max={props.maxX}
     {...cssProps}
     onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
   />
 )
}
```

Here is the CSS use for my slider

```
.itx-slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #373c45;
  outline: none;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #373c45;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 2.5px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-range-thumb {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #373c45;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 2.5px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-range-progress {
  background-color: #373c45;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-range-track {
  background-color: #f4f6f9;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-fill-lower {
  background-color: #373c45;
}

.itx-slider::-webkit-fill-upper {
  background-color: #f4f6f9;
}
```

Thanks you for your help :)